# Migrate to archivedData from archiveRootObject

Tags: ios, swift

I have two model swift files under below.

```
// Item.swift

import UIKit

class Item: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var valueInDollars: Int
    var serialNumber: String?
    let dateCreated: Date
    let itemKey: String

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encode(dateCreated, forKey: "dateCreated")
        aCoder.encode(itemKey, forKey: "itemKey")
        aCoder.encode(serialNumber, forKey: "serialNumber")

        aCoder.encode(valueInDollars, forKey: "valueInDollars")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        dateCreated = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dateCreated") as! Date
        itemKey = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "itemKey") as! String
        serialNumber = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "serialNumber") as! String?

        valueInDollars = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "valueInDollars")

        super.init()
    }
}
```

```
// ItemStore.swift

import UIKit

class ItemStore {

    var allItems = [Item]()
    let itemArchiveURL: URL = {
        let documentsDirectories =
            FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentDirectory = documentsDirectories.first!
        return documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("items.archive")
    }()

    func saveChanges() -> Bool {
        print("Saving items to: \(itemArchiveURL.path)")
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(allItems, toFile: itemArchiveURL.path)
    }
}
```

These two model files confirming to NSCoding protocol and using archiveRootObject to archive the data.

But the archiveRootObject is deprecated, and the NSCoding is not as safe as the NSSecureCoding, how can I tweak the code to adjust all of these?

Comment: With this set of JSON or Property List compliant properties you are encouraged to use the more lightweight `Codable` protocol (which can even serialize structs).

Comment: It seems some persist data only confirm the old NSCoding protocol, so I choice the balance one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite you `saveChanges` function to something like this:

```
    func saveChanges() -> Bool {
        print("Saving items to: \(itemArchiveURL.path)")
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: allItems, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            try data.write(to: itemArchiveURL)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error archiving data: \(error)")
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```